# Spoof index.php with Node.js route

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express

I would like to rewrite my php app in node.js. One of my problems is that we have some legacy client apps written in other languages that point directly to a php file. Is it possible to spoof a php file within an express route?

I have tried the following:

```
app.get('/index.php/', function(req, res){
    res.end('test');
});
```

but typing in {my domain}/index.php/ gives me

> Cannot GET /index.php

What I'd love to have is a routes file called legacy.js, then over time as the legacy apps are updated then I can remove the routes one by one.

Cheers for any help,

Robin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of suggestions

### Suggestion 1

You are getting a 404 from your route above due to the trailing slash in the route definition. Change to:

```
app.get('/index.php', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('PHP route called!');
});
```

### Suggestion 2

Instead of trying to make Node handle your PHP file execution, why not setup nginx/apache as a reverse proxy for node? For instance, with `nginx`, we can run PHP scripts and a node backend server simultaneously:

```
upstream node {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    root /path/to/root/directory;
    index index.php;

    # Here we list base paths we would like to direct to PHP with Fast CGI
    location ~* \/tmp|\/blog$ { {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # Here we set a reverse proxy to upstream node app for all routes
    # that aren't filtered by the above location directives.
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://node;
        proxy_redirect off; 
    }
}
```

This allows you to run both PHP and node on the same domain and without the headache of forking child processes for each PHP script to execute — not to mention the memory impact this would have on your machine.